# Why only gitattributes and gitignore files are getting pushed to repository while committing the code using Visual studio 2019

Tags: git, .net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I created a .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019.When I try to publish my code for the first time using Team Explorer only 2 files i.e. gitattributes and .gitignore are pushed to master repo.

Below are the steps which I followed.

1.Right-click on solution in Solution Explorer and choose Add Solution to Source Control.

2.Navigate to the Push view in Team Explorer by choosing the up arrow icon in the status bar.

3.In the Push view in Team Explorer, selected the Publish Git Repo button under Push to Visual Studio Team Services.

Comment: So, did you `add` (stage), `commit`, and `push` the other files? If not, then they won't be in Git... [Edit] to explain what all you have done in between creating the project and pushing to Git, and to show what VS displays in the Changes/Included/Untracked tabs.

Comment: It sounds like you just did not "Check In Pending Changes", maybe?: [Adding Content to Source Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/adding-content-to-source-control) doc. Git only tracks files that are explicitly added to be committed, and if a file has never been added to any commit, it is never tracked. Perhaps VS does not automatically assume that you want to track all files, and you must tell it.

Comment: @underscore_d Why to check in pending changes this for the first time I'm adding the project to Azure Devops master branch this is the most followed way to add project in Azure devop

Comment: Asking "why" does not answer whether you have tried it and whether it fixed the problem. "this is the most followed way" _What_ is? Where did you get that guide?

Comment: "Adding" something to your index in a git repository means there's nothing to push, since it's not yet committed. Did you get any feedback from 3) ?

Comment: @Vishal Dhasal Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Vishal Dhasal It seems that through the `Add to Source Control` option, it can work normally. If my answer is helpful, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio2019 16.7.5 version, the "Add Solution to Source Control" option has been cancelled, and replaced by the "Create Git Repository..." option. You can try to repair or update VS to the latest version.

[image]

If you don’t want to update, you can try to select [Add to Source Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops#create-a-local-git-repo-for-your-project) on the status bar in the lower right hand corner of Visual Studio to see if this works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I didn't update VS .I will try to follow your solution too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it worked but this is what I have done

Step 1--> In team explorer I clicked on Add to source control
[image]

Step 2-->Navigate to the Push view in Team Explorer or in Solution Explorer by choosing the up arrow icon in the status bar.

[image]

Step 3--> 2. In the Push view in Team Explorer, select the Publish Git Repo button under Push to Azure DevOps Services

[image]

Following above steps Code was successfully published in Azure DevOps Repo